# Groovy (or Java): How to escape double quotes only within HTML inner text, not in attributes

Tags: java, html, groovy, html-entities

I am using a HTML rendering engine based on Groovy within a WCM system.
I now have the use case, that the user enters rich text content within a TinyMCE-based form, which looks like this:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
    <span style="text-decoration: underline;"
        sed diam nonumy
    </span> eirmod "tempor" invidunt ut labore et...
</p>
```

Within my Groovy renderer, I now want to feed this HTML snippet into the HTML document's content to client-side JavaScript processing.

What I need to do is:
Escape double quotes WITHIN content (see "tempor" token above), but not those encapsulating HTML attribute values (see "text-decoration" attribute above).

If I do

```
myHTML.replace("\"", "&quot;")
```

I will in fact escape EVERY double quote.

Any suggestions how I can only escape the quotes WITHIN the real text?

Comment: I think this requires HTML parsing. Then the text inside parsed tags can be retrieved, changed and set back into it and finally, the HTML output regenerated. Have you tried JSoup - https://jsoup.org?

Answer (score 0):

Converting my comment into this answer.

You can use JSoup ([jsoup.org](https://jsoup.org)) in this manner to achieve this. (In your sample HTML, I have added two more places with quotes for the sake of testing.)

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;
import org.jsoup.nodes.TextNode;

public class JSoupEscQuotes{
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        String html = "<p>Lorem ipsum \"dolor\" sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,\r\n"
                + "    <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">\r\n"
                + "        sed \"diam\" nonumy\r\n"
                + "    </span> eirmod \"tempor\" invidunt ut labore et...\r\n"
                + "</p>";
        
        Document document = Jsoup.parse( html );
        
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String s = replace( document );
        System.out.println( document );
    }

    private static String replace( Node node ){
        List<Node> cs = node.childNodes();
        if( cs == null || cs.size() == 0 ) return null;
        
        for( Node c : cs ) {
            if( c instanceof TextNode ) {
                TextNode t = (TextNode) c;
                TextNode tReplaced = new TextNode( t.text().replaceAll( "\"", "&quot;" ) );
                t.replaceWith( tReplaced );
            }
            else replace( c );
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you are using Gradle, include JSoup like this. Or you may use the equivalent Maven configuration, if you are using Maven.

```
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.14.3'
```